# Compiling with Boost::Python, cmake and windows

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-python

I am trying to compile a tutorial project with Boost::python using cmake on windows.

I installed Boost using

```
.\b2 --with-python --toolset=msvc-14.1 architecture=x86 address-model=64 link=shared --user-config=user-config.jam
```

The user config contains

```
import toolset : using ;
using python 
: 3.6  # Version
: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe  # Interpreter
: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/include  # inc dir
: C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/libs  # link libs
: <toolset>msvc
;
```

the cmake file is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)

project(tutorial)
  # Find default python libraries and interpreter
  find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
  find_package(PythonInterp 3 REQUIRED)
  find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)

  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS     OFF)
  SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED    ON)
  SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME     OFF)
  find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED COMPONENTS python36)

  message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES = ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")
  message(STATUS "PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
  message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES = ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

  # Build and link the pylib module
  add_library(pylib MODULE pylib.cpp)
  set_target_properties(pylib PROPERTIES SUFFIX .pyd)

  target_link_libraries(pylib ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

cmake is able to find the boost_python library

```
Boost_LIBRARIES = optimized;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib/boost_python36-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib/boost_python36-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib
```

But I still get the following error during compilation:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'boost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib'
```

Anybody have any insight on what is going on? why is the linker still unable to find the library file.

I am loosely following this guy's [example](http://www.recheliu.org/memo/pythonboostcmakemucheasierthabboostbuild).

Comment: `MAJOR_VERSIONPY` and `MAJOR_VERSIONPY` look like macros that haven't been defined properly, see [Compile problems when trying to link to 1.67.0 python library #193](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/193)

Comment: @VTT thanks, I manually set the major and minor macro value and the thing now compiles. But loading the resulting pyd file in python creates an error. I guess that's another problem entirely XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to VTT answer's, I needed to set the `PY_MAJOR_VERSION` and `PY_MINOR_VERSION` to the correct value.